MPI/C: matrix column-major handling
I am thinking over data distribution in parallel computing with ScaLAPACK, in particular when it comes to matrix data distribution. In the guide it says:

Every process owns a collection of blocks, which are contiguously stored by column in a two-dimensional ``column major'' array.
(https://www.netlib.org/scalapack/slug/node76.html)

At the same time I know that, using MPI-IO, FORTRAN stores data in a column-major style, while in C data is stored in a row-major fashion.
I am pretty confused, so I have a theoretical question: I am programming in C, and doing this sequence of steps:

read some matrices from some files (in a parallel way)
use them to do something (i.e. multiplication)
write the result back into a file (again, in a parallel way).

My doubt is the following: where in this steps the data should be column-major?
An example: consider the matrix
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

It has to be treated, at some point, in a column-major fashion.
Should it be into the content of the (input) file? (STEP 1) E.g., should the file contain
1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9

or the data "storage" distribution is not relevant? E.g.
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Or, after the matrix is read (after STEP 2), e.g., by 3 processes, should the distribution be
           this (col-maj)    or  this (row-maj)?
proc. 0 -> 1 4 7                 1 2 3
proc. 1 -> 2 5 8                 4 5 6
proc. 2 -> 3 6 9                 7 8 9

Or, again, in my example I have to multiply the matrices just read (STEP 2), is it sufficent to have the row-major distribution and just work with efficient indexing (i.e. i-k-j)?
For STEP 3, what said for step 1 applies.
The summary of this question is: where should be the matrix actually be treated as column-major in the steps between input -> computation -> output?

The "data 'storage' distribution" is very important.  If the data is to be read in column-major order, then you need the sequence 1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9, I believe.  But, wouldn't it be quicker to experiment?  It shouldn't take any time at all to produce the two data file options and read the code into an MPI program using the same data reading code you'd use in your full-scale program and then print the data and see which, if either, input layout gives you the correct result.  Don't forget to check the error return values from any functions you call.

If you're not using a function from MPI to read the data but doing it yourself, then you can decide which layout you want to use and assign the data to the MPI matrix correctly.  As long as you're self-consistent, either format is usable.
